# BackgroundTransferRequest status WaitingForWiFi when TransferPreferences is set to AllowCellularAndBattery

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, background-transfer

When I create a `BackgroundTransferRequest`, with `TransferPeferences` set to `AllowCellularAndBattery`, I sometimes still get a `TransferStatus` set to  `WaitingForWiFi`. Is there any way to force the transfer to occur over 3G? This is very weird, as sometimes I start 4 transfers, and 2 of them will be fine, and the other 2 will get into the `WaitingForWifi` state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem may be with file size - see Background Transfer Policies - there are limitations for transfer by 3G. When the file is too large TransferPreferences automaticallly changes.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955(v=vs.105).aspx

For now it seems to be no way to force transmission over 3G if policies are not ok.

Comment: Ah, that's it, some of the videos are slightly bigger than 20MB :(